# PhpMyAdmin - error. Что делать?

Tags: php, windows, phpmyadmin

Перехожу на Demo-phpmyadmin, а там такая ошибка:

> Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log
>   file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that
>   cookies are enabled in your browser.
>
> session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: Read-only file
>   system (30)

Что делать?

Comment: Операционная система какая? Если *nix, то проверьте свободное место в разделе с директориями `/tmp` и `/var` - смотрите вывод `df -h`

Comment: Я новичок в php. (Если скажу глупость простите) у меня операционная система Windows

Comment: Нужен перевод фразы `please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly`?

Comment: Вот перевод: 
пожалуйста, проверьте ваш PHP и / или журнала веб-сервера файл и настроить установку PHP правильно. Кроме того, убедитесь, что куки разрешены в Вашем браузере.

Comment: Мне-то перевод не нужен :) Я думал, Вы не можете перевести. Потому как написано как раз "что делать".

Comment: Да написано что делать но как например попасть в "журнал веб-сервера" и как там что настроить?

Comment: Если новичок, то удали то что ты установил, чтобы не мучаться с настройкой и установи wamp, так тебе будет на много проще. У тебя проблема в настройках файла php.ini скорее всего.